# How to select a DIV and specify a controller for it in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

In my AngularJs Project I have a DIV tag which contains the main navigation bar in my project.

This navigation bar has it's own specific controller which called "topNavController".

I've recently modified my app in order to load everything -somehow- lazily using RequireJs .

The problem is this controller is not dependant on any view/route and has to be loaded directly after my App.js loads .
I'm bootstrapping my app from my RequireJs main file using :

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

If I do like :

```
<div ng-controller="topNavController">...</div>
```

I get an error which says :

```
Argument 'topNavController' is not a function, got undefined
```

which I think it's because myApp is not bootstrapped at the moment Angular tries to bind this controller to my DIV.

I appreciate any suggestions, workarounds or solutions for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is not suficcent enough to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by removing

```
ng-controller='topNavController'
```

and making a directive for it, I put all the code from topNavController to topNavDirective and used directive's controller instead.

Thanks to "iScor" hint in the answer above !

here is how the last version of my main RequireJs file looks like :

```
require(
[
    'app',
    'routeResolver',
    'services/authService',
],
function () {
    require(["directives/topNavDirective"]);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss ng-app to launch the angular bootstrap method.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="topNavController"></div>
</div>
```

You should use directive for this behavior

Comment: Yes thanks! Using a directive is another good solution for this but my problem is that this top navigation bar is used in all other pages. therefore if I want to add a directive I should add an additional topNavDirective dependency on all my routes as I'm lazyloading my App.js, my Controllers, Services and Directives.